# Delete an array element based on value from nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-unset

I have try to remove whole parent array using PHP `unset(key)` function based on value from a nested array in it.

Nested array looks like

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [ID] => 9909 
    [SHIPPING_AMOUNT] => 5 
    [TOTAL_TAX] => 0 
    [GRAND_AMOUNT] => 49.97 
    [ITEMS_AMOUNT] => 44.97 
    [ITEMS] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [CODE] => TEST
            [QTY] => 1 
            [UNIT_PRICE] => 14.99 ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [CODE] => NNKIT 
            [QTY] => 1 
            [UNIT_PRICE] => 9.99 ) 
        [2] => Array ( 
            [CODE] => MAINKIT 
            [QTY] => 1 
            [UNIT_PRICE] => 19.99 )
        ) 
    ) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [ID] => 9910 
    [SHIPPING_AMOUNT] => 5 
    [TOTAL_TAX] => 0 
    [GRAND_AMOUNT] => 74.96 
    [ITEMS_AMOUNT] => 69.96 
    [ITEMS] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [CODE] => NNKIT 
            [QTY] => 1 
            [UNIT_PRICE] => 9.99 ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [CODE] => MAINKIT 
            [QTY] => 3 
            [UNIT_PRICE] => 19.99 ) 
        ) 
    ) 
[2] => Array ( 
    [ID] => 9911 
    [SHIPPING_AMOUNT] => 5 
    [TOTAL_TAX] => 0 
    [GRAND_AMOUNT] => 44.98 
    [ITEMS_AMOUNT] => 39.98 
    [ITEMS] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [CODE] => MAINKIT 
            [QTY] => 2 
            [UNIT_PRICE] => 19.99 ) 
        ) 
    ) 
[3] => Array ( 
    [ID] => 9912 
    [SHIPPING_AMOUNT] => 5 
    [TOTAL_TAX] => 0 
    [GRAND_AMOUNT] => 29.98 
    [ITEMS_AMOUNT] => 24.98 
    [ITEMS] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [CODE] => TEST
            [QTY] => 1 
            [UNIT_PRICE] => 14.99 ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [CODE] => NEWTEST
            [QTY] => 1 
            [UNIT_PRICE] => 9.99 )
        )
    )
```

and value which I check for is `CODE = MAINKIT`. If not exists in a nested array then main array should be removed (in this case parent `array[3]`) but somehow returned `key` is from nested array not a parent one.

PHP code:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value) && $value['CODE'] != 'MAINKIT')
          unset($key);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CODE` elements are inside the `$value['ITEMS']` array, not directly in `$value`.

To tell whether `MAINKIT` isn't in any of the items, you have to loop through all the items, testing whether any of them matches. If none do, then delete the array element.

Try:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if (is_array($value) && is_array($value['ITEMS']))
        $found_mainkit = false;
        foreach ($value['ITEMS'] as $item) {
            if($item['CODE'] == 'MAINKIT') {
                $found_mainkit = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$found_mainkit) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like is doing similar to mine, just one step further - deleting nested `ITEMS` array not the whole parent array

Comment: It's deleting `$array[$key]`, not `$item`.

Comment: I see the problem, give me a sec.